# PNG losses transparency when used as a link

Tags: css, png, transparency, href

I have an image over a table that has been style with CSS. When I have my image on the table without a href it is fine, once I apply an href the transparency is no longer working. Any way around this?

Table css

```
table.list_data {
background-color:#F3F3F3;
border:1px outset #A1A1A1;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:2px;
font-family:'MS Shell Dlg';
font-size:13px;
font-style:normal;
font-variant:normal; 
font-weight:normal;
width:100%;
}
```

Happens in Chrome and FF, haven't tried IE but I expect the same.

html.....

```
<td><a href="javascript:loadContent('#action','addjob.php?id=31');"><img alt="Add A job" src="images/add.png"/></a></td></tr><tr><td>joe bloggs</td>
```

Comment: Which browser(s)? Sample HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the following:

```
a{
  background: transparent !important;
}
a img{
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

This is not a terribly good idea to do in a production site. This indicates that there is something wrong with your css code. Try looking through the css and find whatever is causing your anchor tags to have a non-transparent background.

Comment: It, too, looks to me as if there is an inherited CSS rule that was forgotten. @jason: Do you have Firebug? Can you verify in the "HTML"/Style tab, that neither a nor img have background colors set?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assure that you have transparent PNGs no matter how the code is, use TweakPNG.

http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/